# RegexReplace issues

Tags: google-sheets, formula

So i have this Formula, and it works great, it finds, and counts instances where a name appears, with a given text from AD:AD in the previous column that has Square brackets.

> `=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY({regexreplace('All Report Sheet'!$B$1:$B, "\[|\]",),'All Report Sheet'!$C$1:$C},"select count(Col1) where (Col1 matches '"&JOIN("|",REGEXREPLACE($AD$2:$AD, "\[|\]",))&"') and Col2='"&$A14&"' label count(Col1) ''")))`

I have recently seen that it is not counting names with regular brackets so i tried to tweek it to allow that to the Below formula, but i'm having no luck at all, i'm not sure of the issue.

> `=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY({regexreplace('All Report Sheet'!$B$1:$B, "\[\]\(\)",),'All Report Sheet'!$C$1:$C},"select count(Col1) where (Col1 matches '"&JOIN("|",REGEXREPLACE($AD$2:$AD, "\[\]\(\)",))&"') and Col2='"&$A65&"' label count(Col1) ''")))`

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: did you write the formula?

Comment: Not entirely, the Regex that worked was kindly provided on here for the Squared Brackets

Comment: it looks like it was from Player0.  maybe you should ask a follow up where you originally posted?

Comment: I thought once a question was closed it was done

Comment: @MattKing nice Sherlocking :)

Comment: @player0 inappropriate use of the INDEX() is a dead giveaway! ;)

Comment: Howdy! Can you send DM's on here?

Comment: @KGRsL I'm not fully confident of your Sheets layout or how the shown formula fits into that, but you could perhaps try `"\[|\]|\(|\)"` instead of `"\[\]\(\)"`. RegEx uses `|` as an or statement, and I notice the RegEx portion of your second formula is missing any `|`.

Comment: can you share a sheet for the class?

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, a sample sheet would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.